# Visual Studio TFS doesn't deploy web project

Tags: iis, deployment, continuous-integration, azure-devops, cd

I am using Visual Studio team services (visual studio online). I have a visual studio solution with 12 projects including a Web project (front end), which I set up. I had setup a build and deploy pipeline and successfully deployed the project to IIS but on checking the deployed files I found that the Web project wasn't deployed, just the class libraries. Navigating to the website url gives and "unauthorised response".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to these steps to deploy web app:

1. NuGet Restore task to restore packages
2. Visual Studio Build task (Solution: ***.sln; MSBuild Arguments: /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true  /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\"); Platform:xxx(e.g. $Buildplatform); Configuration: XXX(e.g. $(BuildConfiguration))
3. [WinRM-IIS Web App Deployment](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-winrm) task: (Machines:XXX; Admin Login: XXX; Password: XXX; Web Deploy Package: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\XXX.zip; Website Name: XXX

Comment: But I am using IIS Web App Manage and IIS Web App Deploy how do I combine them

Answer (score 0):

Works now, I just changed the Visual Stuio Version (in the build definition) to Visual Studio 2015, because that is where the app was written